# When trying to check is checksum of a file changed, I get an error "There is no service named file.yaml"

Tags: linux, monitoring, monit

I'm using Monit tool for monitoring on server.
I'm trying to check if checksum of a file changed:

```
set daemon 10
set alert me.mylastname@coorp.com
set httpd port 2812 and use address localhost
 allow localhost
 allow admin:Monit

check file config.yaml with path /home/mydir/config.yaml
 if changed checksum then alert
```

When running "monit restart all" I get an error
"There is no service named file.yaml"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Monit is kind of picky with non-quoted strings. If you need a check name with a dot or space, you need to quote it:

```
set daemon 10
set alert me.mylastname@coorp.com
set httpd port 2812 and use address localhost
 allow localhost
 allow admin:Monit

check file "config.yaml" with path /home/mydir/config.yaml
 if changed checksum then alert
```